# Audio file won't play on simulator on iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios

I have the following code and the sound_file is found.  Also I get no errors.  The audio file is added to the bundle.  But I get no audio out on the iOS simulator.

```
- (void)playNotificationSound
{
    NSString *sound_file;
    AVAudioPlayer * audioPlayer;

    sound_file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"onebell" ofType:@"caf"];
    if (sound_file){

        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:sound_file];
        NSError *error;
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
        //audioPlayer.delegate = self;
        audioPlayer.volume = 1.0f;
        [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
        [audioPlayer play];
    }
}
```

Comment: does it work on the iPhone?

Comment: are you getting soundfile??? is it going in if condition??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a strong reference to your `AVAudioPlayer`. Because you are using ARC and the `AVAudioPlayer` will not live in memory when your `playNotificationSound` finish executing. And a string reference to it can stop it from being deallocated.

Just add a `@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;` And use `self.audioPlayer` instead of declare a new `AVAudioPlayer` variable.

Comment: This worked!  I would of never found it.  I want to make sure I understand....The audioplayer is running async and when this routine ends ARC deletes the audioplayer object so it won't play.  Changing it to a property with (strong) keeps the audioPlayer around in memory.  Is that correct?